# Codebuild Getting error pulling existing and valid ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr, amazon-codebuild

I'm trying to set up a service role for codebuild that miminizes access. I created the CodeBuild project to pull a builder from an ECR based image rather than using Jeff Bezo's precanned builders. Unfortunately, it refuses to let itself do the job:

```
BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for <myacct>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-ecr, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: CodeBuild
```

Inline policy for service role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:DescribeImageReplicationStatus",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetRepositoryScanningConfiguration",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetRegistryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRegistry",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetRegistryScanningConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:<myacct>:repository/my-ecr"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to migrate to non-inline policies, but want to work on getting these working inline then I plan to better organize them. Why is Jeff fighting me on this?

Comment: IAM permissions have nothing to do with the error message, which tells you that you need to login the docker registry you're trying to use

Comment: See step #3 in this official guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-ecr.html